# Where does this formula of absorption cross section come from?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, absorption

My professor gave us a formula for absorption cross section, but he said he did not remember where he found it.

The formula is given by

$$\sigma_a =\frac {1} {|\mathbf E_i|^2} \int_V k \epsilon^{''}_r |\mathbf E|^2 dV = k \epsilon^{''}_r |\frac 3 {\epsilon_r +2}|^2 V .$$

Where does this formula come from? I want to know what those variables stand for.

Comment: For cross section for which type of absorption (or reaction)? What is absorbing to what?